# C++ - Matching the strings with wildcard characters

Tags: c++, wildcard

I'm trying to match the given phrases with the input phrases that may contain ? and * as the wildcard characters.

? means one or more occurrences of any characters (can be different)
* means zero or more occurrences of any characters (can be different)

I'm able to solve the * character part with code below:

```
bool wildCardMatch(char *a, char *b) {
if(*a=='\0' && *b=='\0')
return true;

if(*a=='*' &&   *(a+1)!='\0' && *b=='\0')
return false;

if(*a=='*')
return wildCardMatch(a+1,b) || wildCardMatch(a,b+1);

if(*a==*b){
return wildCardMatch(a+1,b+1);
}

return false;
}
```

However, I'm stuck with the ? character. How can I use the same technique for * character with ? character?

Examples:

"t*x*y" =="txy" (true)

"t?x?y" == "txy" (false)

"t*x*y" == "taxxmmnny" (true)

"t?ble" == "tabcdble" (true)

Comment: Shouldn't it be obvious that this can simply be done by making sure that ? matches any character, first, and then treating it exactly like '*'? Although the shown code has certain inefficiencies, it should work just as well for the ? character too.

Comment: Any reason you don't use indents in your code?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Could you be more elaborate with respect to the code? I got what you meant, but I'm unable to get the desired solution because I've used recursion here.

Comment: @Daniel, well I used Code::Blocks for this particular code and did so in haste, so...

Comment: Any reason why you are not using a regular expression for this task?